# How to make a barrier drived by master program?

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, c++20

Currently I want to build a simple synchronization system based on many working threads + a master thread which manage others and need to synchronize them sometime.

My limitation:

- Stay into standard c++ (or experimental), so can use std::barrier and new c++20 system.

Here, my unit test:

```
int main()
{
    const Barrier::NumberThread nbThreads = 60;
    Barrier barrier;

    barrier.initialize(nbThreads);

    bool needSync = false;
    bool compute  = true;

    std::vector<bool> isSyncs;
    isSyncs.resize(nbThreads);
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::thread>> threads;
    threads.resize(nbThreads);

    // Build threads
    auto itSync = isSyncs.begin();
    for (std::unique_ptr<std::thread>& thread : threads)
    {
        *itSync = false;

        thread = std::make_unique<std::thread>([&, itSync]()
            {
                while (compute)
                {
                    if (needSync)
                    {
                        *itSync = true;
                        // Wait here until master wake up threads
                        barrier.synchronizeThread();
                        *itSync = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Normal working
                    }
                }                
            }
        );
        ++itSync;
    }

    // Check initial state
    for (const bool threadSync : isSyncs)
    {
        assert(!threadSync);
    }

    // Sync all
    needSync = true;
    barrier.masterWait();

    for(const bool threadSync : isSyncs)
    {
        assert(threadSync);
    }

    // Now all is sync
    needSync = false;
    barrier.masterContinue();

    // Stop all threads
    compute = false;
    for (auto& thread : threads)
    {
        thread->join();
    }

    barrier.release();

    // Now guaranty: result is stable
    for (const bool threadSync : isSyncs)
    {
        assert(!threadSync);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My first try can be found here (but synchronization doesn't work): https://ideone.com/xJLHbK

Thanks !

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to achieve? Elaborate on one real world use case would help.

Comment: Currently I want to use this system about Vulkan rendering sync. Typically, I have a thread by view just to execute my rendering loop (commandBuffer + swap acquire ). Sometime, I need to stop rendering (because I delete my window and surface or I need to compute another CommandBuffer). I have a manager to do that (collect all signals and drive threads), it's allow to call properly vkDeviceWaitIdle one time by master and avoid concurrency edition of used memory (like textures). But never mind, I'm intellectually interested by a solution of this problem too !! :-)